# VB.Net Task result is automatically converted to Task(of Task)

Tags: vb.net, async-await

I'm trying to convert a sub to be async and, according to every documentation (and as far as I can remember, I did it in the past), it says that I should convert my sub to a `Function() as Task`.

My problem is that as soon as I hit enter, it is modified to `Function() as Task(of Task)`. To make  sure it was not something inside my method, I did an empty one but it resulted in the same behaviour. I also tried doing ctrl+z to force to keep `as Task` but then I get, on the method,

> BC36945 Visual Basic AND  VB.NET The 'Async' modifier can only be used on Subs, or on Functions that return Task or Task#Of T#.

and on the caller,

> BC36930 Visual Basic AND  VB.NET 'Await' requires that the type 'Task' have a suitable GetAwaiter method.

Is it normal? Is it a new behaviour in 4.6.1? Or is there something additional I should do to have it work as expected and return void?

Note: I'm on Framework 4.6.1 with TupleValue nuget installed.

Comment: It is not normal.  Sounds like you have another type named Task in your project.  Spell out the full name, System.Threading.Tasks.Task to see if that alters the behavior.

Comment: @HansPassant I feel dumb... you're totally right. I imported Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data. I saw it immediately when I hovered Task... Could you write an answer so I can right you?

Comment: Can I know why I got downvoted? Is it really just because I didn't know that quoting would give what I wanted to achieve in formatting? Or is it because I didn't realise flipping it upside down that I simply had an Import I forgot about? BTW, thank you @djv for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned by @HansPassant, for Task to be used directly without its full namespace (`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`), the correct import must be present (which is generally the case by default) and no other namespace should collide with it.

In my specific case, I had `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data`imported which also contains a Task type so when VS modified my signature for async with `as Task(of Task)`, what was really there was `as System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Task)`.

In my project, I fixed the ambiguity by adding `Imports Tsk = System.Threading.Tasks`and then I was able to simply write `as Tsk.Task`.